# iText form filling missing PDF content

Tags: forms, pdf, itext

I am running into an odd problem with iText. I have a document with a few fields. On my server, I open the local document, set the fields and send the output of the stamper to the browser.

Works perfectly on my local devel machine.

The pdf generated on the server is missing the PDF contents. I only see the content of the fields I set, the rest is completely blank.

Any tips?

Comment: Which version of iText are you using. This sounds like a bug that was already fixed. Maybe you're using a version that has the bug on your server, and a version where the bug is fixed on your local machine.

Comment: It is 2.17, I am using gradle/ dep. management: a version mismatch is not impossible but unlikely to happen.

Comment: That version has been declared dead a very long time ago. You shouldn't expect an answer, although I know what is going wrong now that I've read your question a second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application on your local machine respects the bytes of the PDF you're using as a template. Your application on the server doesn't respect those bytes. Maybe you've copied the template using the wrong encoding, making all the binary characters corrupt. Or maybe your application is reading the template using the wrong encoding with the same result.

You can find out by opening your PDF file in a text editor (not inside a PDF viewer). Look for the keyword `stream` and inspect the bytes that follow this keyword. Do you see the difference? In the PDF produced on your local machine, the bytes look like a normal binary stream. In the PDF produced on your server, the bytes look awkward. For instance: it consists of plenty of question marks.

How to solve: check if the template was copied correctly. If so, check the way you're reading the document. For instance: read the PDF template into a byte array without using iText and write it to a new byte array. Can you reproduce the process of corruption? If so, tweak your application (the one that doesn't involve iText) until you've got the correct encoding.

Comment: thanks. I was suspecting this, and I already switched between input stream and byte[] without success. The file is delivered inside a WAR archive, so I suppose I don't have a corruption happening there. I will check my PDF tool (the one that created the FORM ontop of the document) to see if I have any encoding options.

Comment: Actually, even just reading the PDF and sending it to the outputstream of the servlet shows the same problem. Not sure if it is the reading from disk or if it is the packaging/ deployment procedure that is corrupting the file.
It is not an iText issue, that version being dead or not...  ;-)

Comment: It's an encoding problem. It can be caused by the way the file is stored on the server, it can be caused by the encoding used by the JVM, it can be caused by the encoding used in your code,... You'll have to search for every possible encoding problem ever documented (there are many and it's hard to debug these problems remotely).

Comment: I moved the file out of the war into AWS S3, the problem is gone. Not going to do further testing, thanks for helping.